# c# string list reading single element, Console.Read() Problems

Tags: string, console-application

Lets say I have a Test.csv file which is

```
Screen Name,Tweet ID,Dates,Tweets
OilGasMalaysia,5.21E+17,10/13/2014,Dropping Oil Prices Send Shockwaves Through Energy Sector - http://t.co/2dne6NGwRE http://t.co/hRUXjEQGCz
OilBRK,5.22E+17,10/13/2014,Oil prices down in Asian trade as weak demand weighs: Oil prices fell in Asian trade Monday on growi... http://t.co/yuL4D0FPx7 #Oil #BRK
OilBRK,5.22E+17,10/13/2014,Oil prices down in Asian trade as weak demand weighs: SINGAPORE: Oil prices fell in Asian trade Mond... http://t.co/RNBIRiQCu3 #Oil #BRK
OilBRK,5.22E+17,10/13/2014,Oil price down again on growth fears: Global oil prices fall again with Brent crude at a near four-y... http://t.co/AHUrTYORK2 #Oil #BRK
OilBRK,5.22E+17,10/13/2014,Oil heads for four-year low on Saudi output signal: Brent crude oil fell below $88 a barrel on Monda... http://t.co/O4JUbdFQ5o #Oil #BRK
```

I have the program below and I want to load Test.csv using StreamReader

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<string> CsvFile = new List<string>();

        int counter = 0;
        string line;

        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
           new System.IO.StreamReader("Test.csv");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            CsvFile.Add(line);
            // Console.WriteLine(line);
            counter++;
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }

        file.Close();

        for (int i = 0; i < CsvFile.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(CsvFile[i].ToString() + "\n");
            Console.Read();

        }

    }
```

Every thing is fine and file is loading into the memory, but when it go to the for loop each two elements are showing In one line, the problem is related to Console.Read().

Question : 
How to show next **single element** when user press a key using a loop.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're hitting Enter, which is actually two characters -- a carriage return and line feed.  If you change the Console.Read() to a Console.ReadLine(), it will work.